# Add span tag to each element in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tags

Suppose that I have an array. How can I wrap each element in the array in a `span` tag? Also, if I want to `.appendchild` each `span` element to a div element, how can I do it?

```
 function add_span(arr){  
     var new_arr= document.createElement("span");// arr is passed in correctly 
     var text=document.createTextNode(arr); // text cannot be output
     new_arr.appendChild(text);
     return new_arr;
 }
```

and in the main:

```
 for (i = 0; i < unique_array.length; i++)
 { 
     span_array[i]=add_span(unique_array[i]);
 }
 var cloud_text=document.createTextNode(span_array);
 cloud.appendChild(cloud_text);
```

the output now looks like this:
`[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement],[object     HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement],[object HTMLSpanElement]`

Comment: Google: DOM manipulation & append div.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show the questioner put any effort into answering the question for her/his self.

Comment: Isn't an array of HTMLSpanElements what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

[**JSFiddle Example (Updated)**](http://jsfiddle.net/pab75s9r/5/)

Assume that you have an array of strings:

```
var arrayExample = ["apple", "orange", "pear"];
```

Iterate through each string within the array:

```
arrayExample.forEach(main);
```

Append the array string item into a `span` object, and then into a `div` object:

**Edited**

```
function main(arrayItem, index, array) {
    var spanObj = "<span>" + arrayItem + "</span>"
    var divObj = document.createElement('div');
    divObj.innerHTML = spanObj;

    // Do something like:
    document.body.appendChild(divObj);

    // Replace old array string with new array string wrapped in <span>
    arrayExample[index] = spanObj
}
alert(arrayExample); // will output your new Array
```

Comment: I am not sure why but I keep getting the <span> tags in my output. function span_c(arr){
arr="<span>"+arr+"</span>";
return arr;
}  // and in the main : for (i=0;i<unique_array.length;i++){
 unique_array[i]=span_c(unique_array[i]);
 }

Comment: It says in your question that you want the output to be wrapped in a span. What is desired return for `arr`?

Comment: more accurately I want to wrap each element in the array in a span

Comment: So say you have `array = ["1", "2"]`. You're trying to turn the array into `array = ["<span>1</span>", "<span>2</span>"]`?

Comment: Have you seen the Fiddle example? Add a `debugger;` line in the code and update -> You can step through the function and see exactly what each step does.

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through all of the array elements and add span tags to the beginning and end like so:

```
var example = [];

for(var i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
    example[i] = '<span>' + example[i] + '</span>';
}
```

This adds the html span tags to your text and then your array element inside. The `i` acts as the identifier for which array object you are moifying.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better

Comment: When I do this, it makes it a string, right? then when I display it, is should something like <span> apple </span>. Apparently, I do not want <span> to display.

Comment: @Barranka Thanks, I was in a rush but I've updated now.

Comment: @YINGL Yes it will make it a string but because `<span>` is a HTML tag, you won't see it outputted to your screen.